# Using apex:inputCheckbox in a repeat

Tags: apex, visualforce

How can I loop the repeat and display the `apex:inputCheckbox`?

**Error**

> Unknown property 'n'

**Controller**

```
public List<String> ListOfNames {
    get {
        List<String> nameList = new List<String>(); 
        for(String s : /*SOQL*/) { 
            nameList.add(s.Name);
        }
        return nameList;
    }
}
```

**Visualforce page**

```
<apex:repeat value="{!ListOfNames}" var="n">    
    <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!n}"/> 
</apex:repeat>
```

Here is what I want the output to be look like:

[image: Desired Layou]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to use the [`apex:selectCheckboxes`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_selectCheckboxes.htm) tag. Below is a simple demo:

**Controller**

```
public with sharing class Throwaway
{
    public List<SelectOption> options { get; private set; }
    public List<SelectOption> selections { get; set; }

    public Throwaway()
    {
        options = new List<SelectOption>
        {
            new SelectOption('1', 'One'),
            new SelectOption('2', 'Two'),
            new SelectOption('3', 'Three'),
            new SelectOption('4', 'Four'),
            new SelectOption('5', 'Five')
        };
        selections = new List<SelectOption>();
    }
}
```

**Page**

```
<apex:page controller="Throwaway">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:selectCheckboxes value="{!selections}" layout="pageDirection">
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!options}" />
        </apex:selectCheckboxes>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Note the `layout` attribute. It defaults to `lineDirection` (horizontal), which is not what you want. Hence the change to `pageDirection`, which makes it vertical.